# Change store id of the order at the time of checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, store-id

In my website i can change the store as per the region from the front end , but while placing the order , i want to change the order store id as per the product 
vendor region store id even if the website is in another region(store id) . How can i set the store id as per the product's vendor region store id while checking out the order.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar where I change the Store Id at checkout based on the customers billing address.