# Invoice or Receipt in Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, invoice

I have an online eshop developed with Magento 2.1.7 and I have a problem in checkout.

I want my customers to have choice between casual receipt and invoice.

I am not intrested to heve extra fields in in Address Settings Form.

The only one that I want is to have a checkbox or an multiple choice module, in which the customer will say its decission and of cource it will be saved in a way in order to be visible from employees.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **extension_attributes**
on checkout page you can add radio with invoice/receipt 
after place order you can save data like in: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180371/magento-2-save-additional-data-to-order)