# Custom data in custom column of sales order table not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom column in order table of Magento 2 with the name:

> order_detail_data

Now, I want to save some custom data in this column by using

```
sales_order_place_before
```

My Observer code against above-mentioned event is:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderPlacebeforeSaveData implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession

) {
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $orderDetailData = $this->_coreSession->getOrderDetailSession();
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order->setData('order_detail_data', json_encode($orderDetailData));
    $order->save();
}
}
```

But unfortunately, I am not able to save data in this column.

Comment: Did you get value in $orderDetailData ?

Comment: yes i am getting an array in $orderDetailData and after that i convert into string

Comment: Change your event to sales_order_place_after.

Comment: my observer code is fine ?

Comment: Is it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event or as SohelRana said you can use `sales_order_place_after` and add this below code :

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $orderDetailData = 'your value';
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setData('order_detail_data', json_encode($orderDetailData));
            $order->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sales_model_service_quote_submit_before and sales_order_place_after not saving my data to my custom database column. My data is saving in my logs but not in my database.

Comment: In which table you create custom column?

Comment: creating a column with name order_detail_data in database table sales_order_grid

Comment: yes this is working. actually i was trying to store it in sales_order_grid table but it should be save in sales_order table.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly I said to you. Happy coding !! Happy to Help :)